# Unable to receive a permanent access token for my Shopify App

Tags: oauth, access-token, shopify

I'm following the Shopify instructions to get a permanent token for a particular app/shop combination (http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html).

I'm able to get the temporary token and then use a simple html form to receive a permanent token:

But the response I get is: {"error":"invalid_request"}

Can you help me, please?
I searched everywhere (Stackoverflow, Shopify support forums, etc...) but cannot find a clue on how to solve this.
My app is online and hosted on Heroku.

Thanks,

[image: image 3]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 1]

Comment: Can you post the raw request and response? The API key you are using would help as well.

Comment: I added some images showing the full response I get.  There is also the API key (client id).  Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think we have similar minds! I was experiencing the exact same issue as you. I think we were both confused by the documentation!

I generated my app using the `shopify_app` gem. This created the following method in `login_controller.rb`:

```
def finalize
  if response = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params['shop'], response['credentials']['token'])
    session[:shopify] = sess        
    flash[:notice] = "Logged in"
    redirect_to return_address
    session[:return_to] = nil
  else
    flash[:error] = "Could not log in to Shopify store."
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

Line 3 of that (`ShopifyAPI::Session.new`) is doing [Step 2 of the Shopify Authentication](http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html#step_2) for us. It's fetching us a permanent access token.

The variable `sess` will now contain two things:

1. The *.myshopify.com domain of the shop (`url`)
2. **A permanent access token to save for future use** (`token`)

As John Duff said - we already have an access token! **We don't need to POST** to `https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token`. It's handled for us in the code generated by the `shopify_app` gem.

In my finalize method, I added a line:

```
def finalize
  if response = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params['shop'], response['credentials']['token'])

    Shop.find_or_create_by_myshopify_domain(sess.url, access_token: sess.token)
  ...
```

This creates a shop and assigns it the access token. My Shop model has the attributes `myshopify_domain` and `access_token`.

In the future, if I want to use the ShopifyAPI for that shop, I can just follow the instructions found on the [shopify_api gem homepage](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api)

I spent hours trying to nut this one out. I'm not sure how the documentation could be clearer. Hopefully if the issue comes up again, people find this StackOverflow page!

I hope this was a help for you.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: Thank you Nick, I just returned to office from a few days of holiday and found your awesome reply.  Thank you very much, your solution worked beautifully.  Cannot figure why the shopify gem doesn't say this clearly!

Comment: Bam. If I could upvote this more than once I would. Perhaps I'll roll out a 'shopify_app' add-on gem that easily provides the option of storing permanent tokens.

Comment: In my testing the token returned in env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['token'] is the same as the "exchanged" token. Is that not the case for others?

Answer (score 1):

Once the code is used once it expires, you need to store the token or request a new code. In the logs one of your requests succeeded, then you continued making access token requests with the same code which failed because the code was expired.

Try requesting permission again and making the access token call with the new code that you receive. Make sure to store the access token because the code cannot be used again.

Comment: Thanks John, you are right but I never succeeded in receiving a valid access code.  I tried with 3 different tokens but even when a token is new and never used before I get the same reply: {"error":"invalid_request"} :(

Comment: This is not what I'm seeing from the request logs, I think there might be something up with whatever library you are using. Have you tried it with cURL from the command line?

Comment: Thanks John, I tried requesting a new code and then trying again to receive a new access code with this cURL command line command: curl -d "client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&code=xxx" https://discoverstore.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token

Comment: What I am seeing is on July 3 at 5:19 UTC a access token request with grant_type and redirect_uri params passed and user agent Ruby that succeeds. I then see a number of requests for access tokens using the same code that was already used, including the cURL request. Whatever you are doing initially that you are using to grab the code is doing the full exchange, then for some reason you are trying to use the code again to exchange it for another access token.

Comment: Are you using some sort of library that is handling some of this for you?