# Shopify OAuth authentication does not return permanent access token

Tags: oauth, access-token, shopify

I am developing a shopify app with rails and I am following both these links for the OAuth2 authentication: `http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html` & `https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api`.

I have become stuck at the step where I ask for the permanent access token. I have POSTed the client_id, client_secret & code parameters to `https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token` as specified in the authentication documentation however I do not receive the access token. The response I get is Status 200 with an empty body and header.

Code:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("https://#{params[:shop].to_s.strip}")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/admin/oauth/access_token")
request.set_form_data({
    "client_id" => ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key,
    "client_secret" => ShopifyApp.configuration.secret,
    "code" => params[:code].to_s.strip
})
response = http.request(request)
```

Response:

```
@body=[],
@header={},
@status=200,
```

What is confusing me even more is (I could be wrong here, but) the shopify_app doesn't seem to do this step.
I also found this similar question: [Unable to receive a permanent access token for my Shopify App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273462/unable-to-receive-a-permanent-access-token-for-my-shopify-app) but It hasn't been answered yet.

Edit: removed `.myshopify.com` from `http = Net::HTTP.new("https://#{params[:shop].to_s.strip}")` as it was a typo.

Edit 2:
I have tried posting from an HTML form which gave me results, however I was not able to get this to work inside my code using either the example above or with the rest-client gem.
Still very confused as to whats happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the provided answer on the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273462/unable-to-receive-a-permanent-access-token-for-my-shopify-app).

If that isn't the same issue for you then can you post the raw request and response data that is being sent/received? The api key you are using would help as well.

I would suggest trying it with curl on the command line, if that doesn't work you can post each curl string for each step along the way.

shopify_app depends on omniauth and [omniauth-shopify-oauth2](https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2) which handles the oauth authentication.

Comment: I was able to get an access token when I sent the parameters from a basic html form, so I think that the issue may be with the way I am posting the data from inside my app.

Comment: Also the token thats returned from omniauth-shopify-oauth2, is that the permanent access token or the temporary one?
Im totally open to being wrong here, as I'm still learning, but it looks like the temporary one to me.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify does return the Permanent Access Token, but the **ACCESS_MODE must be "Offline"** for the token to be permanent.

With **ACCESS_MODE offline**, your app receives the permanent access token to make requests whenever you want, without the user's permission.

**Documentation:**

> https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth#step-2-ask-for-permission
> https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/authentication#api-access-modes